# Very basic XCode Objective-C question

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm making a simple program in Objective-C.  It has one class with a lot of methods.  I'd just like to put the methods in another file... so I could move the following

```
- (void) myfunc1 {...}
- (void) myfunc2 {...}
// more functions
```

to another file and replace the above w/ something like

```
#include "myNewFile.something"
```

I'm fine w/ putting the #include (or whatever) statement just right in the original file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Chances are that if a class has enough methods to justify splitting it into files, it would be better structured as more than one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to split your methods in to different "categories," which each get their own h and m files.  You'll also need an h and m file for the class itself.  Here's a simple little example that I think will show you what you need to do.

TestClass.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
}
@end
```

TestClass.m

```
#import "TestClass.h"
@implementation TestClass
@end
```

TestClass+Category1.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TestClass.h"
@interface TestClass(Category1) 
-(void)TestMethod1;
@end
```

TestClass+Category1.m

```
#import "TestClass+Category1.h"
@implementation TestClass(Category1)
-(void)TestMethod1 {
NSLog(@"This is the output from TestMethod1");
}
@end
```

TestClass+Category2.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TestClass.h"
@interface TestClass(Category2) 
-(void)TestMethod2;
@end
```

TestClass+Category2.m

```
#import "TestClass+Category2.h"
@implementation TestClass(Category2)
-(void)TestMethod2 {
NSLog(@"This is the output from TestMethod2");
}
@end
```

Then in whatever file is using your class, you'll use

```
#import "TestClass.h"
#import "TestClass+Category1.h"
#import "TestClass+Category2.h"
```

Now you can create an instance of class TestClass and it will have all the methods from both category1 and category2.  Simply use

```
TestClass* test = [[TestClass alloc] init];
[test TestMethod1];
[test TestMethod2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a header file and include it as appropriate.

If you move all your code to "newFile.m", create "newFile.h" and put all your method signatures in the header file. Then in your old file, do "#include oldFile.h".